# $2\pi^2(x-1)^2+4a\cos(2\pi x)-9a^3=0$ For which $a$ has only one solution...

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

For which values of real parameter $a$ the following equation has only one solution:
$$2\pi^2(x-1)^2+4a\cos(2\pi x)-9a^3=0$$

Frankly I have no idea and I hope you'll give me some understandable hint to help me find the way to solve this exercise. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $w = 2\pi(x-1)$.

Then $\cos(2\pi x)=\cos(2\pi x - 2\pi) = \cos w$.

Function $$f(w) = w^2+4a\cos w-9a^3$$ is **even function**.

So, if $w_1$ is solution of equation $$f(w)=0,$$ then $w_2=-w_1$ is solution too.

So, if equation $f(w)=0$ must have only $1$ solution, this solution must be

$$
w=0.
$$

Then you'll get equation for $a$:

$$
4a-9a^3=0.
$$

$\cdots$

Comment: There are three possible values for $a$.